# Android Emulator Networking Issues

Tags: android

Good day all,
I am a newbie in android development and I am having this challenge with my project:
 in my android code am trying to make a HttpURLConnection conection to a servlet at:
http://localhost:8080/CataractServer/CataractServlet

running on tomcat on the PC same where the android emulator is installed.

The problem is that it is resolving the localhost to mean the android phone itself so
the code never connects to the servlet and keeps throwing exceptions.
How can i get the emulator to connect to the servlet runing on my pc.
I dont have access to a lan, i would have put the servlet on another pc and use the ip.

Comment: try http://10.0.2.2/CataractServer/CataractServlet

Answer (score 2):

localhost in this case would refer to your android device and since there is no webserver running there, you would get nothing. You should use `10.0.2.2`. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: wow, thanx a lot. its now working fine. I really am most grateful for all the help.